# knapsack algorithm not returning optimal value

Tags: optimization, python-2.7, combinatorics, knapsack-problem

I am trying to write an algorithm in python for knapsack problem. I did quite a few iterations and came to the following solution. It seems perfect for me. When I ran it on test sets,

- it does not output optimal value
- and sometimes gives maximum recursion depth error.

> after changing the maxValues function it is outputting the optimal value, But it takes very very long time for datasets having more points. how to refine it

For the second problem, I have inspected the data for which it gives the error. The data is like huge and only just couple of them exceeds and the knapsack capacity. So it unnecessarily goes through the entire list.

So what I planned to do is at the start of running my recursive function, I tried to see the entire weights list where each weight is less than the current capacity and prune the rest. The following is the code I am planning to implement.

```
#~ weights_jump = find_indices(temp_w, lambda e: e < capacity)
#~ if(len(weights_jump)>0):
#~ temp_w[0:weights_jump[0]-1] = [] 
#~ temp_v[0:weights_jump[0]-1] = []
```

My main problem remains that why it is not outputting the optimal value. Please help me in this regards and also to integrate the above code into the current algorithm

The following is the main function. the input for this function is as follows,

A knapsack input contains n + 1 lines. The first line contains two integers, the first is the number
of items in the problem, n. The second number is the capacity of the knapsack, K. The remaining
lines present the data for each of the items. Each line, i ∈ 0 . . . n − 1 contains two integers, the
item’s value vi followed by its weight wi

```
eg input:

    n K
    v_0 w_0
    v_1 w_1
    ...
    v_n-1 w_n-1


def solveIt(inputData):

# parse the input
lines = inputData.split('\n')

firstLine = lines[0].split()
items = int(firstLine[0])
capacity = int(firstLine[1])
K = capacity
values = []
weights = []

for i in range(1, items+1):
    line = lines[i]
    parts = line.split()

    values.append(int(parts[0]))
    weights.append(int(parts[1]))

items = len(values)

#end of parsing


value = 0
weight = 0
print(weights)
print(values)
v = node(value,weights,values,K,0,taken);   



# prepare the solution in the specified output format
outputData = str(v[0]) + ' ' + str(0) + '\n'
outputData += ' '.join(map(str, v[1]))
return outputData
```

The following is the recursive function

I'will try to explain this recursive function. Let's say I 'm starting off with root node and now I ill have two decisions to make either to take the first element or not.

before this I will call maxValue function to see the maximum value that can be obtained following this branch. If it is less than existing_max no need to search, so prune.

i will follow left branch if the weight of the first element is less than capacity. so `append(1)`. 
updating values,weights list etc and again call `node` function.

so it first transverses entire left branch and then transverses right branch.

in the right im just updating the values,weights lists and calling node function.

For this function inputs are

> 1. value -- The current value of the problem, It is initially set to zero and is it goes it           gets increased
> 2. weights list
> 3. values list
> 4. current capacity
> 5. current max value found by algo. If this existing_max is greater than the maximum value that can be obtained by following a branch,
>      there is no need to search that branch. so entire branch is pruned
> 6. existing_nodes is the list which tells whether a particular item is taken (1) or not (0)

```
def node(value,weights,values,capacity,existing_max,existing_nodes):
v1=[];e1=[]; #values we get from left branch
v2=[];e2=[]; #values we get from right branch
e=[];           
e = existing_nodes[:];
temp_w = weights[:]
temp_v = values[:];

#first check if the list is empty
if(len(values)==0):

    r = [value,existing_nodes[:]]
    return r;



#centre  check if this entire branch could be pruned. it checks for max value that can be obtained is more than the max value inputted to this 
max_value = value+maxValue(weights,values,capacity);
print('existing _max is '+str(existing_max))
print('weight in concern '+str(weights[0])+' value is '+str(value))
if(max_value<=existing_max):
    return [0,[]];



#Transversing the left branch

#Transverse only if the weight does not exceed the capacity
print colored('leftbranch','red');
#search for indices of weights where weight < capacity
#~ weights_jump = find_indices(temp_w, lambda e: e < capacity)
#~ if(len(weights_jump)>0):
    #~ temp_w[0:weights_jump[0]-1] = [] 
    #~ temp_v[0:weights_jump[0]-1] = [] 

if(temp_w[0]<=capacity):
    updated_value = temp_v[0]+value;
    k = capacity-temp_w[0];
    temp_w.pop(0);
    temp_v.pop(0);
    e1 =e[:]
    e1.append(1);
    print(str(updated_value)+' '+str(k)+' ')
    raw_input('press ')
    v1=  node(updated_value,temp_w,temp_v,k,existing_max,e1);
    #after transversing left node update existing_max
    if(v1[0]>existing_max):
        existing_max = v1[0];
else:
    v1 = [0,[]] 





#Transverse the right branch 
#it implies we are not including the current value so remove that from weights and values.
print('rightbranch')
#~ print(str(value)+' '+str(capacity)+' ')
raw_input("Press Enter to continue...")
weights.pop(0);
values.pop(0);  
e2 =e[:];  
e2.append(0);
v2 = node(value,weights,values,capacity,existing_max,e2);   

if(v1[0]>v2[0]):
    return v1;
else:
    return v2;
```

The following is the helper function `maxValue` which is called from recursive function

```
def maxValues(weights,values,K):
weights = weights;
values = values;
a=[];
l = 0;
#~ print('hello');
items = len(weights);
#~ print(items);
max = 0;k = K;
for i in range(0,items):
    t = (i,float(values[i])/weights[i]);
    a.append(t);
    #~ print(i);

a = sorted(a,key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True);
#~ print(a);
length = len(a);
for (i,v) in a:
    #~ print('this is loop'+str(l)+'and k is '+str(k)+'weight is '+str(weights[i]) );
    if weights[i]<=k:
        max = max+values[i];
        w = weights[i];
        #~ print('this'+str(w));
        k = k-w;
        if(k==0):
            break;
    else:
        max = max+ (float(k)/weights[i])*values[i];
        w = k
        k = k-w;
        #~ print('this is w '+str(max));
        if(k==0):
            break;


    l= l+1;




return max;
```

I spent days on this and could not do anything.

Comment: It is well known and expected that the greedy algorithm quite often does not maximize the value of the knapsack.  You know that, right?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Greedy_approximation_algorithm

Comment: is this a greedy algoritm?

Comment: It is late and I am not following this code precisely.  The greedy algorithm is mentioned in the comments of solveIt(), the greedy algorithm typically picks items with the highest value per unit weight until the knapsack is full.  maxValue() seems to be doing some of that.  ----- Did you know lp_solve will solve knapsacks if you state them as maximizations subject to integer inequalities? http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/

Comment: I've used lpsolve in production, a much much earlier version when it was a stand alone C program.  It works and there now seem to be a lot of APIs for it in different languages. If the goal is to get the answer, I'd try that.  If the goal is to write an algorithm, say for class, it doesn't do that.

Comment: oh that comments are there because i started off with a greedy algorithm and then came to this version. Sorry i did not remove the comments. And this algo is for an assignment submission.

Comment: If you want more intelligent comments, please give examples or test cases, including what inputData in solveIt should look like, and what kind of output it should produce.  Also, any comments you can provide in your code to explain the actual algorithm (or what it is supposed to be doing and why) would help the next person who takes a look.  Good luck.